# Definition of Topology in Munkres' Topology

Tags: general-topology

I am now self-learning ***Topology*** by Munkres, and I am having a question about the definition of topology in this book.

> **Definition**: A **topology** on a set $X$ is a collection $\mathcal T$ of subsets of $X$ having the following properties:
>
> (1) $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in $\mathcal T$
>
> (2) The union of the elements of any **subcollection** of $\mathcal T$ is in $\mathcal T$
>
> (3) The intersection of the elements of any finite **subcollection** of $\mathcal T$ is in $\mathcal T$.

My question is that, why in the second and third points, we need **subcollection**? Can we state the second and third points as

> (2*) The union of any elements of $\mathcal T$ is in $\mathcal T$
>
> (3*) The finite intersection of any elements of $\mathcal T$ is in $\mathcal T$.

I think (2),(3) are equivalent with (2*) and (3*).

To be more specific, to prove $(2)\iff (2^{*})$, if $(2)$ holds, clearly $(2^{*})$ holds since any element of $\mathcal T$ can be regarded as as single-element subcollection of $\mathcal T$ and  the result follows. On the other hand, if $(2^{*})$ holds, it's also obvious that $(2)$ holds since elements of any subcollection of $\mathcal T$ are also elements of $\mathcal T$ by the definition of subcollection and $(2)$ follows. A similar argument would prove the equivalence between $(3)$ and $(3^{*})$.

Hence I want to know whether my proof is wrong and why we need subcollection in the definition.

I apologize if the question is too trivial.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're correct in spirit. However, "the finite intersection of any elements" is just not meaningful, unless you're saying that the sets you choose have a *finite* intersection. This is certainly false. His language is a bit more pedantic because it's important to be precise and it foreshadows things to come a bit later. My advice: Follow his lead.

Comment: What I imagine you mean by (2*) and (3*) is exactly the same as what (2) and (3) mean. But strictly speaking (2*) and (3*) are not gramattically correct; one speaks of the union of a collection of sets, or or a family of sets or of a set of sets,

Comment: Yes, but your statement is slightly less formal. But it is a good reading for an example. Your reading allows for repetitions in the intersection, but that doesn't really change the possible results. So if $U,V$ are distinct open sets, then so is $U\cap U\cap V$ is allowed in your reading, but not Munkres, assuming "subcollection" is a synonym to "subset.") In Munkres definition, you'd need to say "$U\cap U\cap V=U\cap V,$ which is in the topology."

Comment: So these definitions are not exactly the same in meaning - but they are equivalent. There are some cases in your writing that are not in Munkres', but follow pretty easily from Munkres. The real problem is, "What is a finite intersection?" We know what a finite set is, but not a "finite intersection."

Comment: I think you'll also find that's it's useful to stratify your sets to help keep the ideas separated. So for example in Murkes if I see a collection I know that we're working with the open sets of the topology. This is useful since I may want to make elementwise arguments about these collections and so I've put up a sort of notational barrier between. It's can help with bookkeeping.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether your aim is to avoid the use of the word "subcollection" and to find a shorter formulation of the axioms or if you think that the whole *concept of subcollection* is unnecessary in the axioms. Let me first recall Munkres' terminology. Quotation from p. 12:

> When we have a set whose elements are sets, we shall often refer to it as a *collection* of sets.

That is, *collection* is a synonym for *set*, and this synonym is used in a special case. A topology on a set $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ which satisfies axioms $(1) - (3)$.

Here are some remarks.

1. The union of any elements of $\mathcal T$ is in  $\mathcal T$.

This seems to be a sloppy reformulation of $(2)$, but it is imprecise. What is the meaning of *any elements of $\mathcal T$*? The precise meaning is  that you take any subset $\mathcal S \subset \mathcal T$ and form $\bigcup_{U \in \mathcal S} U$. You write

> clearly $(2^*)$ holds since any element of $\mathcal T$ can be regarded as as single-element subcollection of  $\mathcal T$ and the result follows.

Yes, you can identify $U \in  \mathcal T$ with the single-element set $\{U \}$ which is a very special subcollection of $\mathcal T$, but why does this prove $(2)$? You have to consider arbitrarily many elements of $\mathcal T$ and form their union. I am not sure whether you misunderstood something.

2. The finite intersection of any elements of $\mathcal T$ is in  $\mathcal T$.

This is again very sloppy. What you mean is that the intersection of any finitely many elements of $\mathcal T$ is in  $\mathcal T$.